# Only Reading a Certain Range of Coordinates from A Tif File in Raster - R

Tags: r, data-science, geospatial, raster, tiff

I'm trying to read in a large spatial TIF file with raster (about 460 MB).  The goal is to map values from the TIF to certain cities who's boundaries I have defined by shapefiles. The only problem is that my TIF file is too large to fit into memory when I try to convert it into a DF.  Considering I only need TIF values from one country (where the cities are), is there any way I can possibly extract only the select range of latitude/longitude from that country from the TIF file?  That way I can simply just deal with a smaller range of values and then create a dataframe from those.

This is my current code. Raster seems to read the TIF in but a quick inMemory(file) shows that its not in memory.

```
# file is a 460 mb tif file

distances_raster <- raster(file)
inMemory(file) # returns false
# can't convert data it into a DF since doesn't fit in memory
distances_df <- as.data.frame(distances_raster,xy=TRUE)
coordinates(dist_df)<- ~x +y
proj4string(dist_df) <- proj4string(cities_polygon)
extracted_data <- over(dist_df, cities_polygon)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to extract values from the raster where it overlaps with a polygon? The polygons being the `cities_polygon`.

Comment: Ya that part I know how to do.  The issue is just that the TIF is too big to read into memory and Im trying to only read a select lat/long coordinate range.  Thanks

Comment: Okay. I guess I'm not sure what you mean by too big to read into memory. The `raster` package reads in rasters by reference, so not all in memory. Is there any reason you are converting it to a `data.frame`? Is that the part that causes an error?

Comment: Yes I understand.   Ya reading it into a DF is causing the error or when I try to crop the coordinates and add a mask.   Basically anything that tries to get it into memory.   Im only trying to get it into a format where I can apply the over function on it and map its data to my shapefile data.

Comment: I'm not sure why `extract(r, shape)` wouldn't work? If you could share more of your code it would be helpful.